# Java: why don't these variables initialize?

Tags: java

I'm working on an example from Bruce Eckel's book and i was wondering why the initialized values don't stick when I output them?

```
class InitialValues2 { 
    boolean t = true;
    char c = 'x';
    byte b = 47;
    short s = 0xff;
    int i =999; 
    long l =1;
    float f = 3.14f;
    double d =3.14159;
    InitialValues reference; 



    void printInitialValues() { 
        System.out.println("data type       Initial values");
        System.out.println("boolean     " + t); 
        System.out.println("char        [" + c + "]"); 
        System.out.println("byte        " + b); 
        System.out.println("short       " + s); 
        System.out.println("int         " + i); 
        System.out.println("long        " + l); 
        System.out.println("float       " + f); 
        System.out.println("double      " + d);
        System.out.println("reference       " + reference);

    } //end printinitialvalues

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        InitialValues iv = new InitialValues(); 
        iv.printInitialValues();

        //new InitialValues().printInitialValues();

    } //end main 

}
```

All the variables output 0 and null values.

Comment: Where is the class definition of InitialValues? You have listed the code for class InitialValues2.

Comment: @mamin: too bad he couldn't accept a comment as the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see one problem. The variables are declared in a class called InitialValues2, yet you are calling the printInitialValues() method on an object that is of the type InitialValues. It appears that you are never calling your printInitialValues() method.

Comment: Uh...what? I know what that means, but I don't get the context.

Comment: The context would be this isn't really a programming issue, but just a general 'doh'..

Comment: Oh. Meh. "Pwned" was a little excessive there, IMO.

Comment: No it's not. It fits perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

```
class InitialValues { 
    boolean t = true;
    char c = 'x';
    byte b = 47;
    short s = 0xff;
    int i =999; 
    long l =1;
    float f = 3.14f;
    double d =3.14159;
    InitialValues reference; 



    void printInitialValues() { 
        System.out.println("data type           Initial values");
        System.out.println("boolean             " + t); 
        System.out.println("char                [" + c + "]"); 
        System.out.println("byte                " + b); 
        System.out.println("short               " + s); 
        System.out.println("int                 " + i); 
        System.out.println("long                " + l); 
        System.out.println("float               " + f); 
        System.out.println("double              " + d);
        System.out.println("reference           " + reference);

    } //end printinitialvalues

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        InitialValues iv = new InitialValues(); 
        iv.printInitialValues();

        //new InitialValues().printInitialValues();

    } //end main 
}
```

You're class is called InitialValues2 You should rename it to InitialValues.

Comment: Also, if InitialValues is a class that's being used, the object could be changed to "InitialValues2 iv = new InitialValues2();".

Answer (score 3):

Your class name is InitialValues2 but you're creating an InitialValues object.  Replace "InitialValues iv = new InitialValues()" with "InitialValues2 iv = new InitialValues2()"

Answer (score 3):

In the main method you are creating a new **InitialValues**, not an **InitialValues2** (the class posted).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a InitialValues object and calling the constructor for it. But the values you want are in the InitialValues2 class. I am guessing there is some copy pasta error going on.

I may suggest changing your main method to:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    InitialValues2 iv = new InitialValues2(); 
    iv.printInitialValues();
}
```